# android database: insert error (no such column)

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

My App Database is not working...Its showing (Code 1) error showing "no such column"...

My code is as follow...

public static final String TABLE_PROFILE = "profile_icare";

```
    public static final String COL_PROFILE_NAME = "profile_name";

    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String COL_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COL_PHONE_NO = "contact_no";
    public static final String COL_AGE = "age";
    public static final String COL_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String COL_BLOOD_GROUP = "blood_group";
    public static final String COL_HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String COL_WEIGHT = "weight";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_PROFILE +
            "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + " " + COL_PROFILE_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_USER_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_PHONE_NO + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_AGE + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_GENDER + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_BLOOD_GROUP + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_HEIGHT + " TEXT, "
            + " " + COL_WEIGHT + " TEXT " + ");";
    public static final String DROP_TABLE_QUERY = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROFILE;
```

The insert method is as follow:

public void addProfile(ProfileModel profileModel) {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_PROFILE_NAME, profileModel.getFullName());
    values.put(COL_USER_NAME, profileModel.getUserName());
    values.put(COL_EMAIL, profileModel.geteMail());
    values.put(COL_PHONE_NO, profileModel.getPhoneNo());
    values.put(COL_AGE, profileModel.getAge());
    values.put(COL_GENDER, profileModel.getGender());
    values.put(COL_BLOOD_GROUP, profileModel.getBloodGroup());
    values.put(COL_HEIGHT, profileModel.getHeight());
    values.put(COL_WEIGHT, profileModel.getWeight());

    db.insert(TABLE_PROFILE, null, values);

    db.close();

}
```

Comment: which column is missing?

Comment: COL_PROFILE_NAME = "profile_name"

Comment: The logcat is showing this line:

E/SQLiteLog: (1) table profile_icare has no column named profile_name

Comment: did you add it after you created the database ?

Comment: May be I'm not sure...

Comment: uninstall your app and install it again.

Comment: If its like that then what is the solution..?

Comment: Thank you...Let me try it..

Comment: Thank you Sir...Its working... :)